# ActionListener not working as intended

Tags: java, json, swing, actionlistener

Inside of *EditMSFrame* class I have JTextPane in which I have JSON written in it. On button click I check if it is valid JSON.

Now, if I write it like this

```
this.checkButton.addActionListener(e -> {
         System.out.println(isValid(getTextPane().getText()));
});
```

it works fine and writes true/false as I change text inside of JTextPane.

But if I write it like this

```
this.checkButton.addActionListener(new ValidateJSON());
```

--

```
public class ValidateJSON implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        EditMSFrame editMSframe = new EditMSFrame();
        System.out.println(editMSframe.isValid(editMSframe.getTextPane().getText()));
    }

}
```

It will check JSON only once and if it is valid it will print true even if I change if to be non-valid

Comment: Add a constructor to the `ValidateJSON` class which takes an instance of the `EditMSFrame` that is actually on the screen

Comment: And what do I put inside of that constructor?

Comment: You assign a reference of the EditMSFrame to an instance field of your action class

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I'm probably not doing something right tho, care to make edit to my code?

Comment: I menaged somehow to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> care to make edit to my code?

Honestly, I shouldn't have to, this is programming 101. To be frank, you should be consulting a good text book or tutorial, like [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

I'm sorry if this makes me an A-hole, but you'll be a better programming for the effort

```
public class ValidateJSON implements ActionListener {

    private EditMSFrame editMSframe; 

    public ValidateJSON(EditMSFrame someInstance) {
        editMSframe = someInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(editMSframe.isValid(editMSframe.getTextPane().getText()));
    }

}
```